# Building binaries of FF or Chrome for a specific webapp

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

We have a webapp that makes extensive use of JS and Websocket.  Due to time constraints we've only tested on FF and Chrome.  Is there an easy way to build PC/OSX binaries of OSX or Chrome to distribute to users who use IE as their primary browser?

Comment: Why can't you just distribute the existing pre-built binaries?